# Event on a text field Angular

Tags: angular-material, angular-ui-router, pipe, angular-ngmodel, angular2-ngmodel

that's my html code

```
                <optimus-mat-form-field type="input" class="optimus-mat-form-field-width-50">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput maxlength="50" type="text" placeholder="Clé Camelcase" [formControl]="cle_camelcase" title="Clé Camelcase" [(ngModel)]="code" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </optimus-mat-form-field>
                <optimus-mat-form-field type="input" class="optimus-mat-form-field-width-50">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput maxlength="50" type="text" placeholder="Section" [formControl]="cle_section"
                            title="Section" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </optimus-mat-form-field>
```

that's my component
export class ModificationCleComponent extends FormFieldsContainer {

```
toggleReadonly() {
    this.isReadonly = !this.isReadonly;
  }
envExploitDisabled = ["RI","RU","FOR"];

// Formulaire
cleFormGroup: FormGroup;

// Champs
cle_java: FormControl;
cle_camelcase: FormControl;
cle_type: FormControl;
cle_section: FormControl;
cle_desc: FormControl;
cle_active: FormControl;
code:String ;
// Environnements
valeursControls: { valeur: valeurReferentiel, formControl: FormControl }[] = [];

// Modèle
cleReferentiel: CleReferentiel;

// Constructeur
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModificationCleComponent>, private fb: FormBuilder, changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private administrationService: AdministrationService, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) cleReferentiel: CleReferentiel, public habilitationService: HabilitationService) {
    super(changeDetectorRef);

    this.cleReferentiel = cleReferentiel ? cleReferentiel : { cle_id: null, cle_java: null, cle_camelcase: null,
                          cle_section: null, cle_desc: null, cle_type: null, cle_active: true, cle_flag: false }; //cle active par defaut

    this.buildForm();

    // Binding
    this.setUpdateModel(this.cleReferentiel);
}

// Méthode cycle de vie
ngOnInit() {
}
```

in this code I have communication between two text area with NGMODEL, but I want to do some modification on the input value as I showed on the picture below

[result wish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUqLZ.png)

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: What does any of that have to do with "Event on a text field"?